# Trying to retrieve data from a database and use the ResultSet, but don't get the desired output

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database and use the ResultSet , but I don't get the desired output

Main program:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class classname_main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{

    classname abc=new classname();
     ResultSet asdf= (ResultSet) abc.runconnect();



        abc.printdata();

}


}
```

Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class classname{

public static  Object runconnect(){

    try{
        //get connection
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("");
        //Create Statement
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        //ex query
        //Resultset
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("");

        float time=9;



        while(rs.next())

        {

            if(time<20){
            String x=(rs.getString(9));
            Float y=(rs.getFloat(5));
            //System.out.println(rs.getString(""));

            time=time+duration;
            //System.out.println(x);
            if(x>=20){
                x=9;

            }

        }

        }
        return rs;
    }


    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

    return 0;

}

public static Object printdata(){

    classname pd = new classname();
    ResultSet drs =  (ResultSet) pd.runconnect();

    System.out.println(drs);


    return null;
}

}
```

Output:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@5910e440
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.getString(...)` or `.getInt(...)` ...to retrieve desired values like this ex:

```
  System.out.println(drs.getString(some value));
```

Instead of: `System.out.println(drs);`